# conditional Product mathematica

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to replicate Lagrange Interpolating Polynomials in Mathematica.  The wiki for an explanattion of them can be seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).  This is my code (sorry I don't know how to place mathematica code in SO so I have an image):
[image: mathematica error]
My problem is that I want a conditional product.  if j = m I just want to skip over that product and evaluate the next one.  That's why I put the false evaluation as 1.  Any suggestions?

Comment: To put code into stackoverflow, select the code you want and use the Edit menu to copy as "Plain text". You're best only using plain ascii variables and no subscripts, etc... See how I formatted the code in my answer below.

Comment: @Simon Thanks! I forgot about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All built-in functions start with a capital letter. So the conditional is `If[...]` not `if[...]`. Fix that and everything works fine!

```
With[{k = 5}, Sum[Product[
  If[j != m, (x - x[m])/(x[j] - x[m]), 1], {m, 0, k}], {j, 0, k}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I was JUST coming back here to say that!  I can't believe I was making such a novice mistake.  Took me 20 min to find it.  Thanks anyway Simon.

Comment: @Matthew: [Brain farts](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Brain%20Fart) like this happen sometimes...

Comment: Some of us are more gassy than others... (Matthew, I don't mean you.)