# List Manipulation in Mathematica pertaining to Lagrange Interpolation Polynomials in Mathematica

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to use a list which is passed to a function in such a way that I can

- get the length of that list
- get the individual x and y values to manipulate

The list I am trying to manipulate can be seen below:

```
dataTan = Table[{x, Tan[x]}, {x, -1.5, 1.5, .75}];
```

this question is a sort of a follow-up to the question seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410379/conditional-product-mathematica).  I eventually want to write my own function in mathematica that generates the Lagrange Interpolation polynomial for a given set of points

```
 {{x0, y0}, ... , {xn, yn}}
```

I need some way to access the points above so that I may utilize the code below:

```
Sum[Subscript[y, j]*Product[If[j != m, (x - Subscript[x, m])/
       (Subscript[x, j] - Subscript[x, m]), 1], {m, 0, k}], {j, 0, k}]
```

Comment: Matthew, Can you clarify your question so that it is [useful to later generations](http://xkcd.com/979/)?

Comment: Matthew: I'm going to downvote your question until you fix it...

Comment: @Simon I will fix it right now!

Comment: @Simon Upvote for using XKCD!  I wish I had more votes to give for that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8410379/421225), I'm guessing that you mean a [Lagrange Polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial), so

```
LagrangePoly[pts_?MatrixQ, var_: x] /; MatchQ[Dimensions[pts], {_, 2}] := 
   With[{k = Length[pts]}, Sum[pts[[j, 2]] Product[
     If[j != m, (var - pts[[m, 1]])/(pts[[j, 1]] - pts[[m, 1]]), 1], 
     {m, 1, k}], {j, 1, k}]]
```

We can test it against the tangent function,

```
In[2]:= points = Table[{x, Tan[x]}, {x, -1.2, 1.2, .2}]
Out[2]= {{-1.2, -2.57215}, {-1., -1.55741}, {-0.8, -1.02964}, 
         {-0.6, -0.684137}, {-0.4, -0.422793}, {-0.2, -0.20271}, 
         {0., 0.}, {0.2, 0.20271}, {0.4, 0.422793}, 
         {0.6, 0.684137}, {0.8, 1.02964}, {1., 1.55741}, {1.2, 2.57215}}

In[3]:= Plot[Evaluate[Expand[LagrangePoly[points, x]]], {x, -1.2, 1.2}, 
     Epilog -> Point[points]]
```

[image: tan]

In this case, the interpolation is good, the maximum deviation from the original function is

```
In[4]:= FindMaximum[{Abs[Tan[x] - LagrangePoly[points, x]], -1.2<x<1.2}, x]   
Out[4]= {0.000184412, {x -> 0.936711}}
```

---

Also note, that [interpolating polynomials](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html) are actually built into Mathematica:

```
In[5]:= InterpolatingPolynomial[points, x]-LagrangePoly[points, x]//Expand//Chop
Out[5]= 0
```

I had to expand them both before comparison, since `InterpolatingPolynomial` returns the result in the efficient [`HornerForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HornerForm.html), while my `LagrangePoly` is returned in a very inefficient form.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I am having some strange output though.  I will post another question about it.  I hope that is fine.  The output works, I am just having a strange "$" symbol that I've never seen before.

Comment: @MatthewKemnetz You should upvote answers that helped you/are useful... like Simon's here, for instance.

Comment: @yoda I thought I did when I accepted it but I must have missed it.  Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list `l`then you can get the length of that list by using `First@Dimensions@l`. Assuming that the list has the form `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}` you can then get any of the `x` and `y` values at position `index` just by using `Part[l,index]` or its shorthand `l[[index]]`.

EDIT: If you want to do things the simple way you could conceivably use `Length@l` for the length of the list.

Comment: There is a function to find the length of a list. It is called... `Length` :)

Comment: @Yoda: There's moon in the sky, it's called the moon.

Comment: @Yoda: Doh! I'm just so used to Dimensions, since it lets me see if there are any formatting errors in the list.