# "$" symbol in mathematica output

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

I am having some slight difficulty with the following code:

```
Lagrange[list_] := 
  Module[{points = list, length, k, j, m, x, g}, 
    length = Length[points]; 
    k = length - 1; 
    f = Sum[points[[j + 1,2]]*Product[If[j != m, (x - points[[m + 1,1]])/
          (points[[j + 1,1]] - points[[m + 1,1]]), 1], {m, 0, k}], {j, 0, k}]; 
    g = FullSimplify[Expand[f]]; 
    Return[f]]
```

The output I get is:

```
Out[101]= 0. -1.85698 (-1.5+x$26810) (-0.75+x$26810) (0. +x$26810) (0.75+x$26810)
         +0.490717 (-1.5+x$26810) (-0.75+x$26810) (0. +x$26810) (1.5 +x$26810)
         -0.490717 (-1.5+x$26810) (0. +x$26810) (0.75 +x$26810) (1.5 +x$26810)
         +1.85698 (-0.75+x$26810) (0. +x$26810) (0.75 +x$26810) (1.5 +x$26810)
```

My concern is with these "$" symbols.  I don't know what they mean, I can't find documentation on them, and they are preventing the plotting of this polynomial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$` in your output is from the unique variable generated by the lexical scoping of `Module` (see the More Information part of [mathematica/ref/Module](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html)). This is why I made [my `LagrangePoly` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8410755/421225) accept the symbol that the polynomial is meant to be in. I used `LagrangePoly[list_, var_:x]`, which defaults to the global symbol `x`.

A simple example of the problem is

```
In[1]:= Module[{x}, x]    
Out[1]= x$583
```

The number in the "local" variable `x$nnn` comes from the global [`$ModuleNumber`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$ModuleNumber.html).

If you don't understand this, then you should probably read the tutorial [Blocks Compared with Modules](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/BlocksComparedWithModules.html).

Comment: if I want to put this function in a package to be used in another notebook, do you see a need for the use of module in my case?

Comment: @Matthew: If this code is going to be moved into a package, you probably want the flexibility to choose the symbol used in the polynomial. So a symbol `x` should be passed to the function like I suggested. You also don't need `j` or `m` in the `Module`, since they're already scoped by the sum and product. Finally, why did you calculate `g`, but return `f` in your code?

Comment: I removed g from the calculation.  "g" was unnecessary and was from an old version.  Thank you for catching it for me.

Comment: I thought I should let you know...it works perfectly now; just as I hoped.  Thanks for all your help! On to Hermite Interpolating Polynomials!

Comment: Simon, better than `x` would be `\[FormalX]` to avoid most collisions.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, x is a local variable. However you are returning an expression containing x. The purpose of localized variables is that they shouldn't appear outside their context, which is the Module in this case.

Consider this simple example:

```
adder[x_] := Module[{y}, Return[x + y]]
```

`adder[2]`  gives: `2 + y$1048`

A good practice is to recognize that our function adder should actually itself return a function.

```
adder[x_] := Function[{y}, x + y]

twoAdder = adder[2];
```

`twoAdder[3]`  gives: `5`